# Fix tag [elsaticsearch-painless] to [elasticsearch-painless]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There is a typo in the tag [elsaticsearch-painless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elsaticsearch-painless), it should be renamed to [elasticsearch-painless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-painless) instead.

Comment: Ai. That's ... wait for it ... painful.

Comment: What's Elasticsearch Pantsless, and *how* is it on topic?

Comment: @Will here you are -- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just retagged all the questions with the new tag [elasticsearch-painless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-painless), since old tag did not have wiki and stuff. It will be deleted automatically in 24 hours.

Also, I think [painless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/painless) should be a synonym for [elasticsearch-painless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-painless).

Comment: Thanks a lot Vadim, much appreciated!

Comment: Also can you confirm if the top users history of that tag will be lost as well or whether it will carry over to the new tag?

Comment: @Val I'm not sure. There were only 17 questions, so I just went ahead.

Comment: Oh…that would explain why I kept getting strange errors when I tried to do this merge a few moments ago. I guess it isn't a big deal in this case because there were only a few questions with the misspelled tag, but in the future, it would be nice to let a moderator handle this because we can do so without causing the disruption of a bunch of "bumped" old questions.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the info! Can you create a proposed synonym?

Comment: Yes, I can create a synonym, but I don't know why we would want to create a synonym of the misspelling. It only exists because one person mistyped it, and everyone after that just chose it from the auto-complete list. If it doesn't exist anyone, no one will be using it.

Comment: @CodyGray no, I mean second part of my answer: "Also, I think painless should be a synonym for elasticsearch-painless"

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood what you were asking. Yes. Incoming…And live now.